# Jackson writeValue is ambiguous for the type ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I was using Jackson 2.7.9 and everything works fine. But after the routine check of libs for vulnerabilities, this version is no longer safe to use. So I tried to update it to 2.16.0, then my Eclipse say `The method writeValue(OutputStream, Object) is ambiguous for the type ObjectMapper` with red cross and error tag with it.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());) {
        mapper.writeValue(wr, contentObj);
        wr.flush();
    }
```

Tried to looking into it if there is anything related answered, but these are "cannot be resolved", doesn't seem to be fit to mine condition. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version `2.7.9` you were using [ObjectMapper.writeValue(OutputStream, Object)](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.16.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue-java.io.OutputStream-java.lang.Object-).

According to the docs, the overload [ObjectMapper.writeValue(DataOutput, Object)](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.16.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue-java.io.DataOutput-java.lang.Object-) was added in version `2.8`.

[DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) extends [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) and implements [DataOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html). Because of this calling `writeValue` with `DataOutputStream` matches *both* method signatures.

As a solution, you can cast the parameter to the type, required by the method you want to use.

```
mapper.writeValue((OutputStream) wr, contentObj);
```

Or

```
mapper.writeValue((DataOutput) wr, contentObj);
```

Comment: Seem to be working good. A notice about casting is the IDE may not find the proper source of it. Like my Eclipse could not identify `OutputStream` is under `java.io`, so no import option will be shown in the quick fix list. You have to write it as `java.io.OutputStream`.

Comment: @Kaninchen This sounds like a bug in eclipse, if `OutputStream` is imported, there is no need to write the full class name for the cast.

Comment: Not imported in the import list on top, but somehow the Eclipse IDE just can't find the right one and show it in the quick fix list. Mine is 4.29.0, it's quite recent version.